# How to update a label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I go about updating the `numpy` arrays as labels on my Tkinter application?

Code is following:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

# General Tkinter setup
root = Tk()
root.title("Scale Widget")
root.geometry('600x400')
# This is the creation of the sliders
slider1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider1.pack()
slider2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider2.pack()
slider3 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider3.pack()
slider4 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider4.pack()
slider5 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider5.pack()
slider6 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider6.pack()
# This is the collation of the NumPy array
numpyvalueupper = np.array([slider1.get(), slider2.get(), slider3.get()])
numpyvaluelower = np.array([slider4.get(), slider5.get(), slider6.get()])
# Help Here please!
label = tk.Label(root, text=numpyvalueupper, bg="blue", fg="white")

print (numpyvalueupper)
print (numpyvaluelower)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you just want to display the label use `label.pack`.  If not, then do you want to update the np array whenever the slider is moved? do you want to append new values to numpy array or just clear the values and update the array with the new values?

Comment: Yes, I would like to update the NumPy array whenever the slider moves... Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to append values to the numpy array or clear the array and insert new values?

Comment: I think re update the values on the application. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On creation of a tk label you can input a tk.StringVar and set that text to your numpy array.
Here is a little example.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np


def updateLabel(e):
    numpyvalueupper = np.array([slider1.get(), slider2.get(), slider3.get()])
    numpyvaluelower = np.array([slider4.get(), slider5.get(), slider6.get()])
    # Just add these together for an example...
    textvar.set(str(numpyvaluelower + numpyvalueupper))

# General Tkinter setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Scale Widget")
root.geometry('600x400')
# This is the creation of the sliders
slider1 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider1.pack()
slider2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider2.pack()
slider3 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider3.pack()
slider4 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider4.pack()
slider5 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider5.pack()
slider6 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, resolution=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateLabel)
slider6.pack()

# Help Here please!
textvar = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=textvar, bg="blue", fg="white")
label.pack()
textvar.set(str(np.array([slider1.get(), slider2.get(), slider3.get()])))


root.mainloop()
```

Careful with your imports up top there.  You don't need both tkinter imports statements and should just use one format.

Comment: yes this is the answer but you could also use `label.config(text=numpyvalueupper)`